# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/ . . . /node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npx

When I run:
`npx react-native run-android`

It gives the error like this:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/ . . . /node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/...`

when I ran **Command Prompt** as administration still giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of my searches the problem was this `react-native-gesture-handler`, So ***some time just restart you computer*** the error will fix, if that is not fix by restarting the PC then **uninstalled** and after that **reinstalled** this dependency. no need to remove `node_modules` and reinstall all, now the problem fixed.

uninstall:

```
npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

install:

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform the below steps

1. remove `node_modules` folder
2. `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`
3. in your `App.js` import the below line

   import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
4. remove the build folder from `android-> app -> build`
5. `npx react-native run-android`